# Is there any good exhaustive resource for finding idioms by theme?

Tags: resources

Is there any good exhaustive resource for finding idioms by theme? I tried to google some, but the ones I found on google are not very exhaustive. They have maybe 500 idioms in total. I currently use Wiktionary, but I can only search by the word they contain, which isn't very useful.

This one seems to be the best on the Internet, but it's a far cry from what I would like to find:

https://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idioms_proverbs.html

Comment: ELU does not accept resource requests, although its meta does.